# Jquery-ui working fine on localhost in Firefox but not on server?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-plugins

don't know why this Jquery ui is not working on firefox but working in chrome [see here!!](http://engineervilla.com/Picditor/test.html).
also when i run this locally on firefox it works fine can anybody suggest what is the problem my code is

**HTML**

```
<div class="option" id="f" style="display:inline-block;">
  <img class="options" src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/" alt=""/>
</div>
<br>
<div class="lame" style="display:inline-block;">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(function() {
    $( ".option" ).draggable({ cursor: "pointer",opacity: 0.6,helper: "clone"});
    $(".lame").droppable({ 
        accept:".option",drop: function(event, ui) {
            $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;
            $(ui.helper).draggable({cursor : "pointer",opacity: 0.6,containment :".lame"});
            $(ui.helper).find('.options').resizable({containment : ".lame"});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because Chrome is forgiving your incorrect slashes in your CSS and JS paths (they should be forward slashes, not backslashes) and Firefox isn't. Firefox is giving '404 Not Found' errors when trying to load your CSS and JS files.

p.s. when you're running it locally, you're probably using the file:// protocol rather than running your own web server, in which case it seems Firefox will quite happily allow backslashes.